# Sinatra/Rack Sleep until Response Ready (like Exchange ActiveSync)

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra, push, rack

I'm wanting to do a lightweight push-style HTTP response in my existing Sinatra web app. Is there any mechanism that allows me to not respond to an HTTP request and keep the connection open until I wake up the connection at a future time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also check out macournoyer's http://github.com/macournoyer/pusher "The Rack App that pushes" and collin's http://github.com/collin/orbited-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

Could this help ? 
http://macournoyer.com/blog/2009/06/04/pusher-and-async-with-thin/

Comment: Looks like it could be the ticket, I'll play around with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget http://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra.